# implode array and store as complete string based on positions of another array

Tags: php

I have four arrays: `$text[], $ytext[], $titles[], $ytitles[]`

What I want to do is implode the arrays, text and titles, by " " to store them as a complete string. But I want to arrange them based on their position (which is a y coordinate integer).

For example :

```
$text[] = 
{1 => hello
2=>   again
3 => more text
}

$ytext[] = 
{1 => 5
2=>  10
3 => 14
}

$titles[] = 
{1=> title
2=> title2
}

$ytitles[] = 
{1=> 2
2=> 11
}
```

SO this would look like: `title hello again title2 more text`

Comment: I don't understand the requirements, can you give more examples?

Comment: the end result would basically be the sentence at the end.....based on the position of each individual string specified by ytext and ytitles, the individual strings of text and titles would be organized as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Andreas' solution, which was a very good idea, but doesn't quite work because `array_merge()` doesn't preserve numeric keys. You can use this solution:

```
$arr = array_combine($ytext, $text) + array_combine($ytitles, $titles);
ksort($arr);
echo implode(' ', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newText = array_combine($ytext, $text);    // combine $ytext as keys and $text as values
$newTitles = array_combine($ytitles, $titles);
print implode(' ', array_merge($newText, $newTitles)); // merges and implode array
```